# How to open a html file on current browser tab using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have the code below

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ClosePopup.html");
```

ClosePopup.html is the html file below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body onload="window.close()">
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to open this HTML file on the current tab and it will close itself since I cannot close a tab opened by a user, however, this code opens this HTML file in a new tab and instantly closing it so the tab I am trying to close remains open. How can I change the target tab of the `Process.Start()` function?

Comment: I feel like this is an incredibly convoluted way to open a link in a new tab. Is there any reason (special requirement) that would give a need to do this on the server rather than client (i.e. with javascript/anchor tag targets)? Also - why effectively just replace a tab? Why not use the current tab? I really am confused with this one.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to close the tab this way because I am using this code on a form page. If I close the tab on the client then my code cannot get the values written in the form because the tab instantly closes and stops the code. However, I am trying to close the tab after everything in the server-side is done.

Comment: Oh OK, so you simply want to close the tab when the form's submitted? I'd use AJAX for that. I'll post an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do what you're trying to do. Just so happens you are accessing the site on the server itself, so when you start that html process - it's opening on the server. Others accessing your site would never see that.

Given the requirements you added some clarity on in the comments I'd suggest a client-side approach like the following:

```
$("#theForm").ajaxSubmit({url: '[some action]',
                          type: 'post',
                          success: function() { window.close(); }})
```

This has the added benefit of you also being able to only close the window if the response was a successful one. Currently, with the way you're trying to do it, even a failed request would result in a closed tab.